# Solve the system $ \begin{cases} x+y=m\quad \text{where } x=m-y\\ (x-a)^2+y^2=m^2 \end{cases} $

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to resolve a system of equations, but I can't solve it for $y$.

Solve this for $y$:
$$ \begin{cases} 
x+y=m\quad \text{where } x=m-y\\
(x-a)^2+y^2=m^2 
\end{cases} $$

Could someone explains me step by step how to resolve this system by any way please? I can't isolate $y$...

Comment: You have got an expression for $y$ in terms of $m,a$, and that immediately gives an expression for $x$ in terms of $m,a$. What is your question? Are you worried that you have two solutions instead of just one?

Comment: @almagest I just found out the answer, I didn't see I had to use the quadratic formula $X=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection(s) between the circle $\mathcal{C}'_m$ and the slope $d_m$ respect simultaneously their equations.

$$\newcommand{\equivalence}{\Leftrightarrow}
\begin{align*}
     &\begin{cases}
    (d_m) : x+y=m \\
    (\mathcal{C}'_m) : (x-a)^2+y^2=m^2
    \end{cases}\\
    \equivalence &\begin{cases}
    (d_m) : x+y=m\quad \text{where }x=m-y\\
    (\mathcal{C}'_m) : (m-y-a)^2+y^2=m^2
    \end{cases}\\
    \equivalence &\begin{cases}
    (d_m) : x+y=m\quad \text{where }x=m-y\\
    (\mathcal{C}'_m) : ((m-a)-y)^2+y^2=m^2
    \end{cases}\\
    \equivalence &\begin{cases}
    (d_m) : x+y=m\quad \text{where }x=m-y\\
    (\mathcal{C}'_m) : (m-a)^2-2y(m-a)+y^2+y^2=m^2
    \end{cases}\\
    \equivalence &\begin{cases}
    (d_m) : x+y=m\quad \text{where }x=m-y\\
    (\mathcal{C}'_m) : m^2-2am+a^2-2y(m-a)+2y^2-m^2=0
    \end{cases}\\
    \equivalence &\begin{cases}
    (d_m) : x+y=m\quad \text{where }x=m-y\\
    (\mathcal{C}'_m) : 2y^2-2y(m-a)-2am+a^2=0
    \end{cases}\\
    \equivalence &\begin{cases}
    (d_m) : x+y=m\quad \text{where }x=m-y\\
    (\mathcal{C}'_m) : y^2-y(m-a)-am+\dfrac{a^2}{2}=0
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

Here we have a second degree polynomial function. We change the variable as follows $y=\chi$.

Be $f(\chi)=\chi^2-(m-a)\chi-am+\dfrac{a^2}{2}$. To solve for $y$ the system above, we are searching $\chi$ for $f(\chi)=0$ then :

$$\chi^2-(m-a)\chi-am+\frac{a^2}{2}=0$$

Using quadratic formulae we have :

$$\begin{align*}
\Delta&=(-(m-a))^2-4\times1\times\left(-am+\frac{a^2}{2}\right)\\
\Delta&=(a-m)^2-4\left(-am+\frac{a^2}{2}\right)\\
\Delta&=a^2-2am+m^2+4am-\frac{4a^2}{2}\\
\Delta&=a^2+2am+m^2-2a^2\\
\Delta&=-a^2+2am+m^2
\end{align*}$$

There only are solutions to this system (then intersection(s) between $\mathcal{C}'_m$ and $d_m$) if $\Delta\geq0 \equivalence -a^2+2am+m^2\geq0$.

If $-a^2+2am+m^2\geq0$, then :

$$\chi_1=\dfrac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}=\dfrac{m-a+\sqrt{-a^2+2am+m^2}}{2}$$ and
$$\chi_2=\dfrac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}=\dfrac{m-a-\sqrt{-a^2+2am+m^2}}{2}$$

Knowing that $\chi=y$, then we have :

$$\begin{align*}
&\begin{cases}
    (d_m) : x+y=m\quad \text{where }x=m-y\\
    (\mathcal{C}'_m) : y=\dfrac{m-a+\sqrt{-a^2+2am+m^2}}{2}\ \text{or}\ y=\dfrac{m-a-\sqrt{-a^2+2am+m^2}}{2}
    \end{cases}\\
\equivalence &\begin{cases}
    (d_m) : x=-\dfrac{m-a+\sqrt{-a^2+2am+m^2}}{2}+m\ \text{or}\ -\dfrac{m-a-\sqrt{-a^2+2am+m^2}}{2}+m\\
    (\mathcal{C}'_m) : y=\dfrac{m-a+\sqrt{-a^2+2am+m^2}}{2}\ \text{or}\ y=\dfrac{m-a-\sqrt{-a^2+2am+m^2}}{2}
    \end{cases}\\
\equivalence &\begin{cases}
    (d_m) : x=\dfrac{m+a-\sqrt{-a^2+2am+m^2}}{2}\ \text{or}\ \dfrac{m+a+\sqrt{-a^2+2am+m^2}}{2}\\
    (\mathcal{C}'_m) : y=\dfrac{m-a+\sqrt{-a^2+2am+m^2}}{2}\ \text{or}\ y=\dfrac{m-a-\sqrt{-a^2+2am+m^2}}{2}
    \end{cases}\\
\end{align*}$$

If $-a^2+2am+m^2\leq0$, then there's no solution for this system.

$$\square$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{cases} 
x+y=m\\
\left(x-a\right)^2+y^2=m^2 
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\begin{cases} 
x=m-y\\
\left(x-a\right)^2+y^2=m^2 
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\begin{cases} 
x+y=m\\
\left(\left(m-y\right)-a\right)^2+y^2=m^2 
\end{cases}$$

Now, we can solve:

$$\left(\left(m-y\right)-a\right)^2+y^2=m^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left(m-y-a\right)^2+y^2=m^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$a^2-2am+m^2+y(2a-2m)+2y^2=m^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$a^2-2am+y(2a-2m)+2y^2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Using the quadratic formula:

---

$$y=\frac{(2m-2a)\pm\sqrt{(2a-2m)^2-8(a^2-2am)}}{4}$$

Comment: There only are solutions if $\Delta\geq0$, see my answer to my question below : http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1780971/338746.

Comment: @PMC1234 Yes, you're right! That's true.

Answer (score 0):

Just conclude it by plugging your result into you first equation.
You will have
$$
(x,y)= 
\begin{cases}
\left(
\dfrac{a+m-\sqrt{-a^2+2 a m+m^2}}{2},
\dfrac{-a-m+\sqrt{-a^2+2 a m+m^2}}{2}
\right),\\
\left(
\dfrac{a+m+\sqrt{-a^2+2 a m+m^2}}{2},
\dfrac{-a-m-\sqrt{-a^2+2 a m+m^2}}{2}
\right).
\end{cases}
$$